# C# MySQL Registration System - Select Command

Tags: c#, mysql, select, command, registration

I'm making a `C# MySQL` Registration System, and I already have a login system connected to it.
When I register a new user to the database, and try to enter a username which is already in the database, its not working (ofcourse). And I have this command for that:

```
String query = "SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username = @username";
```

I also have a system (in the same project) to register items into the database.

But there I want it to have that you cant add the first and the second value again.

**so for an example:**

I got in my database one item, value1 is "1234" and value 2 is "4321".

But when I add another one, I want it to says (If you enter the same data), **"4321" is already in the database. Or "1234" is already in the database.**

So not just one of them like my Login system.

Thanks :D

Comment: Best way to do this is to make your `username` column in the database as `UNIQUE`, and when you try to insert a duplicate `username` the database will throw an error and you can handle it from code.

Comment: Yeah, i have that already :p, but i want that for both values.

Comment: so when you add an item record you assign it a value1 and a value2? It would be very useful to see your relevant schema

Comment: What? Do i still need the MySQL Data Reader if im going to give the fields an ''UNIQUE" index?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the same as for your user registration?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM values WHERE value1 = @value1 AND value2 = @value2
```

or if you need each individual value to be unique:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM values WHERE value1 = @value1 OR value2 = @value2
```

If that returns a number then you know that value already exists, so show them the error and don't do the `INSERT`.

As unlimit says, the best thing to do would be make the column `UNIQUE` and then handle the error thrown back at you when you execute the `INSERT`.

Comment: I tried to make both fields ''UNIQUE'' but it didnt make any difference tbh, i did insert this line tho:

                        String query = "SELECT 1 FROM uitgifte WHERE laptop = @laptop AND leerling = @leerling";


But where does the "1"stands for?

Comment: By the way, i am making a laptop registration system. for students.

Comment: The `1` just means it'll return a row containing a `1` if it finds anything, and return nothing otherwise. You could change it to a `COUNT(*)`, then it would always return either a `1` (for 1 record found) or `0` (no records).

Comment: so then it  would be something like this? For checking:                         String query = "SELECT (*) FROM uitgifte WHERE leerling = @laptop AND laptop = @laptop";

and for inserting: 

                                        query = "INSERT INTO uitgifte (id, laptop, leerling) VALUES(@laptop, @leerling)";

Comment: Yup except its `SELECT COUNT(*)` not just `SELECT (*)`

Comment: It gives me this error: http://puu.sh/5i8En.png, And it didnt even do anything, just changed my query line to:                         String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uitgifte WHERE leerling = @leerling AND laptop = @laptop";

Comment: what are @laptop and @leering? Assuming you're including those parameters correctly there shouldn't be a way for that query to cause an exception. I have little to no C# knowledge unfortunately (and currently little to no internet, or I'd start a chat with you).

Comment: I'm sorry, but its still not working, and i have no idea how to continue with this, heres my method: http://pastebin.com/khtj062C